# Wifi not working

Tags: debian, wifi, dhcp, internet

I just dual-booted windows 7 with Debian 7, during the installation it said the wifi firmware was missing so I installed without an internet connection, after the installation I got my LAN cable to install various programs but now i'm having problems configuring the wifi connection, on the windows partition wifi works fine.

So first thing I did was install the module for my wifi card, which is:

```
  Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6205
```

I did it by installing [iwlwifi](https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi) on apt-get.
After that it recognized my card, I think, because I could scan for the network:

```
root@debian:/home/user# iwlist wlan0 scan
wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 7A:B6:86:83:0A:08
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=48/70  Signal level=-62 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"NETWORK"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000008c098b443
                    Extra: Last beacon: 2952ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 00074E4554574F524B
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B961224486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C183060
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: 0B05010045127A
                    IE: Unknown: DD07000C4304000000
                    IE: Unknown: 0706434120010D10
```

I then installed iw to try to connect to the network:

```
root@debian:/home/user# iw dev wlan0 link
Connected to 7a:b6:86:83:0a:08 (on wlan0)
    SSID: NETWORK
    freq: 2412
    RX: 33045 bytes (536 packets)
    TX: 1232 bytes (17 packets)
    signal: -59 dBm
    tx bitrate: 1.0 MBit/s

    bss flags:  short-preamble short-slot-time
    dtim period:    0
    beacon int: 100
```

It says i'm connected to the router, but I still don't have internet access.

Some more output:

ifconfig:

```
root@debian:/home/user# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3c:d9:2b:25:51:cb  
          inet addr:192.168.1.72  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::3ed9:2bff:fe25:51cb/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:101484 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:59551 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:139315514 (132.8 MiB)  TX bytes:5061083 (4.8 MiB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:d1500000-d1520000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:343 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:343 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:30800 (30.0 KiB)  TX bytes:30800 (30.0 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a0:88:b4:85:f5:cc  
          inet addr:192.168.1.74  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a288:b4ff:fe85:f5cc/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:297 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:26754 (26.1 KiB)
```

EDIT:

```
root@debian:/home/user# ping 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=1884 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=876 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=0.813 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=4 ttl=64 time=0.814 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=5 ttl=64 time=0.845 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=6 ttl=64 time=0.738 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=7 ttl=64 time=0.737 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=8 ttl=64 time=0.752 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=9 ttl=64 time=0.830 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=10 ttl=64 time=0.762 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=11 ttl=64 time=0.768 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=12 ttl=64 time=0.748 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=13 ttl=64 time=0.784 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=14 ttl=64 time=0.743 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
14 packets transmitted, 14 received, 0% packet loss, time 13006ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.737/197.826/1884.227/518.915 ms, pipe 2


root@debian:/home/user# ping 8.8.8.8
connect: Network is unreachable
```

I also noted I'm not getting an inet address when i connect to the router, only after i type dhclient wlan0:

```
root@debian:/home/user# dhclient wlan0
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.984/0.984/0.984/0.000 ms
```

I do get an inet address. But still no internet, moreover, after getting the inet address pinging the router will output errors:

```
root@debian:/home/user# ping 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.74 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.74 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.74 icmp_seq=8 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.74 icmp_seq=17 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
20 packets transmitted, 0 received, +4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 19120ms
```

EDIT 2:

```
root@debian:/home/user# ip route
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.72 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.74 
root@debian:/home/user# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

EDIT 3:

Currently can't connect to the network at all:

```
root@debian:/home/user# ifconfig wlan0 up
root@debian:/home/user# iw dev wlan0 connect NETWORK keys 1:password
root@debian:/home/user# iw dev wlan0 link
Not connected.
```

I can still scan for the network though.

Comment: Can you ping your gateway? Probably `192.168.0.1` but you'll need to confirm that. If that works, can you ping externally by IP address? Google's DNS server would be a good one - `ping 8.8.8.8`.  Post your results in your question.

Comment: @garethTheRed done, the first ifconfig output was probably after i used dhclient wlan0. Since im not getting an ip automatically.

Comment: This suggests that your routing is incorrect. Check the output of `route` or `ip route`. The former should show you a line similar to `default 192.168.1.1 0.0.0.0 UG 1024 0 0 wlan0`.

Comment: Seems like you are right, any suggestions on fixing this?

Comment: @garethTheRed right, no default gateway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the default route for your network.  This is the 'catch-all' route that is used in the absence of a better one.

The command to add a default route is either:

```
route add default gw 192.168.1.1
```

or:

```
ip route add default via 192.168.1.1
```

The above will not be permanent though.

To make it permanent, either add it to the network scripts in `/etc/network/interfaces` or use `NetworkManager`.

Comment: It did make my route command output like you said it should be, but still I couldn't use the internet (ping on the router also didnt work), so I rebooted to start over and try it again, but now I can't connect to the network at all, iw nor iwconfig let me connect to the network.

Comment: Are you using a Gnome desktop or similar?  In which case, use `Network Manager` to configure it.  There's even a `nmcli` utility to configure it on the command line on later versions.  Have you installed the `firmware-iwlwifi` package?

Comment: I am using openbox, i'll look into the different tools, thanks for all the help, I will report back when I can connect again.

Comment: I installed the Network Manager applet, (wicd didnt recognise my network) and it worked. I still don't know what was wrong with the cli method.

Comment: Glad you got it working - I'm not certain why your command line attempts failed neither. I've not used it much - usually only when `X` fails to start.